# Load TXT file - Refresh the contents

Tags: javascript, html

It's been a while since I tried my hand at HTML - and I'm getting stumped - hopefully someone can come to my aid.

**My goal:** On my LOGIN page, I want to add an "outage" notification section. I don't want the admins to access the login.html file; I want the data to be grabbed from a text file.

**My attempt:** I created an "outage.txt" file which is scheduled to update the webserver every morning. I then use a DIV and OBJ to load the "outage.txt" file. This does work.

```
<table><tr><td>
   <div id="outage"><object width=475 data="outage.txt"></object></div>
</td></tr></table>
```

**My problem:** When I update my "outage.txt" file and refresh the page, the data is **NOT** reflected on the page. The only way I can get it to load correctly is to do a force-refresh (ctrl-F5).

**What I tried:**

-) I added meta data to not use cache. But it still does not update my data.

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />
```

-) I've changed my txt pull to JQUERY. It pulls the data nicely - but still does not update it.

```
$.get( "outage.txt", function( data ) {
```

**Need help:** At this point I'm not sure what to ask help for. Is there a better way to grab a text file and display it on the page? How to I ensure that the page is being correctly loaded and not pulled from cache. Is there a way to FORCE the page to force-refresh?

Comment: Do an [AJAX call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX/Getting_Started) for the file instead of using `<object>`

Comment: A (weird?) old cachebusting trick is to append a random querystring to your request, so instead of requesting "outage.txt" you request "outage.txt?someRandomNumber", for example `"outage.txt?" + Math.random()`

Comment: Thanks James - this is almost working for me. When I manually update the page to "...txt?1", the page correctly updates to the newest data. I'm trying to implement the `"outage.txt?" + Math.random()` code you suggest, but I'm struggling adding it to my code. I'm a bit rusty with javascript ... is there a way to add this into the object-data?

Comment: Combine @Neumy 's with mine?:
`document.getElementById("objid").data = "outage.txt?" + Math.random();`

Comment: Thank you James and dcromley. You guys helped me figure this out. This worked for me and my page is loading the correct data from the text files every time. Heros!!!

Answer (score 0):

When I do a refresh (Ctl-R) on my Chrome, it updates the text.
Try:

```
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById("objid").data = "outage.txt";
}
<object id="objid" width=475 data="outage.txt">
```

Comment: Interesting. This is not working for me; however, it weirdly does everything backwards. Now when I force-refresh the page, I see the new data briefly .. then it reverts back to the old data.

Answer (score 0):

I have my answer and will do my best to summarize it here.

Looks like the browser sees the data="outage.txt" file and says 'Hey! I already have this in cache, no need to grab a file again'. The trick is to force a change to the filename which tells the browser that 'This is a new file, please load it no matter what'.

```
<div id="outage"><object id="outageid" width=475></object></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById("outageid").data = "outage.txt?" + Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
</script>
```